MongoDB - $geoIntersects is not working looking polygon with location
I want to search for the document with my location, depending on whether I am within the polygon.
I have a document like this
{
  ...
  "points": {
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -3.679053009144624,
          43.33304047030704
        ],
        [
          -9.294330256519363,
          44.813402382628816
        ],
        [
          -7.0349117492277395,
          44.3268008169113
        ],
        [
          -3.679053009144624,
          43.33304047030704
        ]
      ]
    ],
    "type": "Polygon"
  },
  ...
}

My query
db.locations.find({
  points: {
    $geoIntersects: {
      $geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [-6.6694316716305755, 44.15774788994904]
      }
    }
  }
})

But it doesn't return any results

I have the 2dsphere index, but it still doesn't work

$geoIntersects uses spherical geometry. What tool did you use to generate that image? Is it similarly visualizing spherical geometry? That's a pretty narrow polygon, feels possible that the point could fall outside of it with spherical geometry

Not sure how is your image plotted. I can get the same plot for the polygon but not for the point. When I am trying to reproduce the issue and plotting the graph, the point is outside of the polygon
